# Adding messages to message array

Tags: c#, msmq, message-queue

if I declare a message array and I also have a MessageEnumerator, how can I add the current message of the enumerator to the array?

```
Message[] m = null;
MessageEnumerator me = q.GetMessageEnumerator2();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        me.MoveNext();
        Array.Resize(ref m, m.Length + 1);
        m[m.Length - 1] = // the current message?
        me.RemoveCurrent();    
     }
```

any tips at all appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put messages into a list then transform it into an array:

```
List<Message> ml = new List<Message>();

MessageEnumerator me = q.GetMessageEnumerator2();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    me.MoveNext();
    ml.Add(me.Current);
}

Message[] m = ml.ToArray();
```

On another note you should not *iterate* (use indices) over an `IEnumerable`, you should instead *enumerate* this way:

```
List<Message> ml = new List<Message>();

foreach (Message mx in q.GetMessageEnumerator2())
{
    ml.Add(mx);
}

Message[] m = ml.ToArray();
```

You can even pour the `IEnumerator` directly into a new list, but this is so tight it doesn't even make sense anymore:

```
List<Message> ml = new List<Message>(q.GetMessageEnumerator2());
Message[] m = ml.ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks, that should sort it. I had done it that way as I only want to add 10 messages